# How do I repaint furniture?

Tags: paint, furniture

I've purchased [this cabinet](http://www.target.com/p/accent-storage-bookcase-cabinet-black/-/A-13864639) recently and would like to know if there is a way to paint it white?

It is described as:

> Frame Material: Hardwood
>
> Wood Finish: Painted
>
> Finish: Painted

[image: Picture of cabinet]
<sub>(source: [targetimg1.com](http://img1.targetimg1.com/wcsstore/TargetSAS//img/p/13/86/13864639.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the doors and all hardware, if you can remove the glass that is even better; if not just mask the glass.  Take a fine grit sandpaper like 320 and sand everything that is black to scuff up the finish (you don't want to paint on a finish).  Get a few cans of white spray paint in whatever finish you want and start spaying.  In multiple light coats allowing time to dry between coats and in a well ventilated area.  Most paints nowadays spays included shouldn't need a primer.

Comment: Do I have to sand it ? How much do I sand, should the black paint completely disappear before I start spraying white ?

Comment: If you don't sand, definitely go with a primer. Actually, I'd suggest a primer anyways just to help cover the black.